Django Ninja multiple APIs documentation
Django Ninja allows to autogenerate OpenApi endpoint documentation. However, the documentation is available for single API object only, meaning that in order to view another API's documentation I need to change the URL.
My project uses multiple API versions. I would like to host the docs under single, unified URL instead of having to remember what api version specific feature used.
Django Ninja's documentation allows API versioning as stated here. However, this leads to the problem described above.
Is there any way to include API version switcher as if I was using standalone OpenAPI docs? Obviously, I could get and host raw docs myself, but I hope that there's an easy configure-and-forget solution I am missing, since Django Ninja hosts it already.
I tried combining different api versions using Router objects instead of API objects. This, however, only is a workaround and prevents some features from working properly. On top of that, wrong API version displays in the UI
